# Passing a function with parameters

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I want to pass a function with parameters into another function without evaluating it.

This method doesn't work:

```
function first (id) {...}

function second (func) {
    func();
} 

second(first(id));
```

This method does but I can't use it because the number of parameters is not always the same:

```
function first (id) {...}

function second (func, id) {
    func(id);
}

second(first, someId);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `#bind` for partial application:

```
second( first.bind(null, id) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper function:

```
second(function () { first(my, parameters); })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use apply if you want to pass in a variable number of params to a function, like this:

```
function runit(func, arrayofparam) {
   func.apply(this,arrayofparam);
}
```

All those docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
function func1(param1, param2){
    console.log("func1");
    console.log(param1);
    console.log(param2);
}

function func2(param1){
    console.log("func2");
    console.log(param1);
}

function executor(func, params) {
     //This do all the trick :)
     func.apply(this, params); 
}

executor(func1, ["first", "second"]);
executor(func2, ["lonely"]);
```

this is the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/xrhkoL5a/ (use browser console to see result).